# How do I access the ResourceManager class in a .NET Core 3.1 project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, localization

I would like to access values in a resx file using the ResourceManager class.  I have included a using statement for System.Resources.  The class does not seem to be recognized when I add it to my code (it doesn't show in intellisense) though I know it is in the System.Resources namespace.  I added the System.Resources.ResourceManager package to my packages in the project.  I still am unable to use the class.  What do I need to do to use the ResourceManager class in .NET Core 3.1, or is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Dumb.  It doesn't show up in intellisense but when I type it out it *is* recognized.  I'm too dependent on intellisense I guess.